# 'list','_AtIndexer' object is not callable PandaPy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> ```
> mp = pd.read_csv("Stock price over the last 24 months of Adidas, Nike, and Puma.csv",index_col=0)
> mr = pd.DataFrame()
> # compute monthly returns
> for s in mp.columns:
>     date = mp.index[0]
>     pr0 = mp[s][date] 
>     for t in range(1,len(mp.index)):
>         date = mp.index[t]
>         pr1 = mp[s][date]
>         ret = (pr1-pr0)/pr0
>         mr.set_value(date,s,ret)
>         pr0 = pr1
> ```

I try to predict the Stock price over the last 24 months of Adidas, Nike, and Puma buy using panda and I'm get error

> ```
>  TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> Input In [60], in <cell line: 3>()
>       8 pr1 = mp[s][date]
>       9 ret = (pr1-pr0)/pr0
> ---> 10 mr.set_value(date,s,ret)
>      11 pr0 = pr1
>
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
> ```

PS: I try to solve by reading same error but i can't solve this.
trying to use ***mr.at*** instead of ***set_value*** and i got another error

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 5>()
     10 pr1 = mp[s][date]
     11 ret = (pr1-pr0)/pr0
---> 12 mr.at(date,s,ret)
     13 pr0 = pr1

TypeError: '_AtIndexer' object is not callable
```

please help

Comment: Quick comment: `pandas.DataFrame.set_value` is deprecated since version 0.21.0. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html

Comment: Thank you for reply. I update the situation i used .at still not solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use **.at** like this:

```
mr.at[date,s]=ret
```

full code:

```
mp = pd.read_csv("Stock price over the last 24 months of Adidas, Nike, and Puma.csv",index_col=0)
mr = pd.DataFrame()
# compute monthly returns
for s in mp.columns:
    date = mp.index[0]
    pr0 = mp[s][date] 
    for t in range(1,len(mp.index)):
        date = mp.index[t]
        pr1 = mp[s][date]
        ret = (pr1-pr0)/pr0
        mr.at[date,s]=ret
        pr0 = pr1
```